# Why do unwanted changes occur when uploading Word doc to Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I'm uploading a Word document to Google Docs. However, when I upload it, all the text boxes that have been carefully positioned in the Word doc all mash up to the top.

Is there any reason for this? It happens both programmatically and when using the web UI.

Comment: Which version of word is the document saved as?

Answer (score 6):

Not every document is compatible with Google Docs.  The conversion process isn't perfect.

Comment: I thought so thanks for the reply, just as I expected.

Comment: well, also try to upload those problematic documents to MS Office Online, http://office.live.com (MS is the .DOC and .DOCX format owner...), so if you have success, you can save them in the cloud.